# Selenium 2.0 WebDriver IE8 findelement by xpath cannot be evaluated

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath, selenium, webdriver

When I run the following code in Firefox it runs correctly, but in IE8 it says xpath cannot be evaluated or does not result in a WebElement.

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='submitForm']")).sendKeys("\n");
```

OR

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='submitForm']")).click();
```

I have tried alternate xpath "//div[@id='parameters']/table/tbody/tr[4]/th/input" but it gives same result.

It seems to me that it is a IE driver problem, please let me know if there is a work around.

Comment: Can anyone tell me, what exactly the reason behind the above error? I could see it only in IE.

Answer (score 4):

Could you try as below?

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[string(@id)='submitForm']")).click()
```

For IE doesn't have native XPath support, WebDriver use a third-party library called [javascript-xpath](http://coderepos.org/share/wiki/JavaScript-XPath) for this, this may be a bug of it.

Answer (score 1):

IE 8 need this top 3 line compulsory in selenium web driver

```
   DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
   ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

   WebDriver webDriver= new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```

Please change Xpath by Id:

```
 webDriver.findElement(By.id("submitForm")).click();
```