# issues in running selenium in internet explorer

Tags: selenium

Hi I am trying to run my selenium webdriver on IE9.

- WebDriver version : 2.32.0
- IE:9
- IEDriverServer_win32:2.32.3
- windows7

Below is my code:

```
File IEDriver=new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"BrowserDrivers"+File.separator+"IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", IEDriver.getAbsolutePath());
DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
driver.get("http://in00616:8421/GS");
Thread.sleep(3000);
//driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("admin");
//driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("admin");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='j_username']")).sendKeys("admin");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='j_password']")).sendKeys("admin");
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).submit();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[text()='Securities']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Issue']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.id("tabSecurities_Issue_Request_for_Issues")).click();
```

Above code logs in to my site but then when I try to click on Securities button I am not able to do it. Securities button starts flickering and then I am notified that unable to find the element.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to find element with xpath == .//span[text()='Issue Type']
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) –

Same code works fine in FireFox.

Please help as i am suppose to test my UI on InternetExplorer.
I think it is the version compatibility issue.
Can anyone suggest the compatible version set for IEDriverServer, Selenium WebDriver and IE which is in working condition.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == .//span[text()='Issue Type'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Since you're trying to call `findElement` immediately after a `submit`, it's possible that IE hasn't had time to render the element you're looking for on the subsequent page. What happens if you use a wait before trying to find the element?

Comment: Hi i have tried using Thread.sleep but still it is not helping it is going till clicking on securities tab but going ahead it stucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all i have found out that it was the issue of Selenium Webdriver 2.32 with IEDriver_Server2_32. After trying out permutation & Combination with latest available webdriver versions and IEDriver_Server, i have found out suitable stable configuration to work on IE9 below is the stable configuration : Webdriver : 2.33.0 IEDriver_Server : 2.33.0. There is still small issue but i am trying to look for workaround. Issue : In IE if some control's tooltip overlaps other control than IE is not able to find out that control. i guess this issue is with IEs working. IE uses nativeEvents to perform operation hence it is not able to locate that control. In FF it is able to find out that control and it is working fine. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

As [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9194981/1221475) points out, IE does not have native XPath support. Instead, Selenium WebDriver uses an old third party xpath library when IE is being used. Firefox has integrated support for XPath, which is why your selectors work fine in that browser.

I would highly recommend you update your selectors to instead use CSS selectors. They are supported across all browser, are easier to read, understand, and pick up, and they are pretty fast.

You can learn more about how to use CSS selectors from some different tuturials [here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors), and [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/), and a [CSS selectors cheatsheet](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/13/css-3-cheat-sheet-pdf/).

Also, whenever possible, please try to not select an element by the text it contains. If you can select an element by its ID, class, other attribute, or even through the DOM chain (i.e. "div.1 > div.2 > span.a > a.b"), is better than trying to select an element by text.

Comment: hi bgoad please see my above edited code i tried using xpaths to login(previously i had used id). if i go by what u say then i should not be able to login. but i am able to login and also click on the securities element but going ahead it stucks. the menu starts flickering. Also i cannot use CSS or ID as i have issues with identifying objects hence i have to go by XPaths. any other solution. I think the issue is with the version that i am using. can anyone suggest IEDriver, Selenium WebDriver and FireFox version which is stable and in working condition?

Comment: No, your code allows you to login because you are using standard XPaths to type in the login fields. Your errors occur when you try to find the Securities tab via an XPath "contains text" method. I am advising that you not use the "contains text" method, and instead find some other selection method to latch on to (i.e. ID, class, tag, etc). With CSS selectors, you can easily intermingle these selectors via a hierarchy, very much like XPath. My main point is that CSS is supported across the board, whereas IE requires an old third party XPath library. Best to steer clear of XPath in this case.

Comment: Hi atleast can any one tell me the compatible version combination of IEDriverServer, Selenium WebDrvier and IE where things are working properly?

Comment: @bgoad, why should not I use 'search element by text'? This way you will not have problems with 'developers changed dom model'. And also such testing will be more close to 'user' thinking, but not developer. Tha latter seems to be more close to idea of testing in general...

Comment: @yashaka text is dynamic on a site, and in my experiences, updated more frequently than IDs or classes. Also, it is more difficult to ensure that you are selecting the right element, as the same text might turn up in multiple places on the AUT. There are times indeed where it is handy (i.e. no identifying attributes for links in a list) as opposed to selecting by index, but in most cases it is best to use actual DOM based selectors to find your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver has difficulty with IE using locators. It seems like Murnal has difficulty using CSS locator. My advice would be you HAVE to use other locators if one doesnt work. This issue comes again and again while using non firefox browser. In the meantime an easier way to come up with alternate locator is use Firefox selenium IDE, there in the boxes where you type command you will see it gives alternate locator as well. Copy that and try plugging tha in your webdriver's findelement script.