# Using Selenium with Python: Clicking multiple 'expand' links that don't contain ID's

Tags: python, html, selenium, expand

I'm trying to fill out a form in IE9 using Selenium and Python.  In the form, there are a lot of 'Expand/Collapse’ links; the only differences between them are the text labels. Also, they don't contain an ID, just 'style' and 'onclick' (there is a line below it with an ID that maybe can be used to look at the parent of?).  I need to be able to click every expand in the form, but right now I can't even click one of them (IE9 doesn’t seem to like xpath very much, and there's no id to search for).   Here’s the section of HTML I’m working with:

```
<tr>
  <td colSpan="4">
    <legend style="cursor: hand;" onclick="expandCollapse(this,'Name1')">
      Text - Name1 (
      <u>
        Text - Expand
      Text - )
    <div id="Naming1" style="display: none;">
<tr>
  <td colSpan="4">
    <legend style="cursor: hand;" onclick="expandCollapse(this,'Name2')">
      Text - Name2 (
      <u>
        Text - Expand
      Text - )
    <div id="Naming2" style="display: none;">
```

Is there a way to be able to click all of the expands when the code is set up like above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rely on the provided `div` elements with `id`s since they are not visible. You'll get `ElementNotVisible` exception in this case.

Instead, try out the following options:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td[@colSpan="4"]/legend[@onclick]')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//legend[starts-with(@onclick, "expandCollapse")]')

driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('legend[onclick^="expandCollapse"]')

driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('legend')
```

There are much more possible ways to get to the `legend` elements. The reason I've provided multiple options is that there is no complete page HTML or link to the target web-site provided.

See also:

- [issues in running selenium in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687942/issues-in-running-selenium-in-internet-explorer)

Hope that helps.