# Unable to locate element in Selenium webdriver 2.0

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, xpath

I am unable to locate this element with the class name. Below is the HTML code:

```
<a class="j-js-stream-options j-homenav-options jive-icon-med jive-icon-gear" title="Stream options" href="#"></a>
```

I tried to create an xpath using class and title both of them did the work in eclipse...ex:

```
//a[@title='Stream options']
//a[contains(@class,'j-js-stream-options j-homenav-options jive-icon-med jive-icon-gear')]
..
```

the None of the above options worked and I tried a few others too...Essentially I want to click on this element and do some action..I want to locate the randomly created xpath so that I can click on the element in the next run.

FYI: the element is a hidden element I need to click on some other element before this element appears. This is a dynamically created element whose expath changes all the time.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the element you want to select in a separate iframe?  If so, you need to switch to the correct iframe (`driver.switchTo().frame("frame-id")`) before firing the xpath selector.

Additionally, something to watch out for is that old versions of IE didn't have a native xpath library.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9194981/3108853) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response...There is no seperate iframe for this element. I am using FF browser. Also when I try to locate the element with the mentioned xpaths above through IDE, the IDE does not give me an error in the console. Usually it does when it is unable to locate the element. But it does to blink the element too..as it usually does. but when the use the same xpath in eclipse it does not work.